# Java external command : not found, createProcess errno=2

Tags: java, windows

I try

```
ProcessBuilder().command("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sc.exe query power");
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder().command("c:/windows/system32/sc.exe query power");
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder().command("c:/windows/system32/sc query power");
```

I always get the same error ...

Comment: Please re-read carefully the Javadoc (especially the examples) for `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: That isn't valid Java code. You're missing the very important `new` keyword to make it valid.

Comment: the new is here, sorry for the partial paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit each argument for `sc.exe` separately to `ProcessBuilder` to avoid issues with argument escaping or quoting. Right now you have the whole command as a single `String` expression, this cause the problem.

Since `C:\Windows\System32` directory should be in the system `PATH` it should enough to do.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sc.exe", "query", "power");
Process p = pb.start();
int result = p.waitFor();
```

Comment: ultimately, I used 

        `new ProcessBuilder("sc", "query",  "power");` 

so yes it's in the path
and yes I think it's the best way to do, because "cmd arg1 arg2 etc.." is interpreted as a single exe name (so with spaces) by the jvm
thanks !